# vb.net list<T> if not exist add

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, generics, generic-collections

I have a List

```
    Public Class Connoisseur
                Public Name As String
                Public Pieces As String
    End Class


Private Sub Button26_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button26.Click
    Dim CS As New List(Of Connoisseur)()
End Sub
```

How to use generics Write an IFNotExistsAdd function

```
CS = {"test1","2"}
```

It looks like this

```
CS.IFNotExistsAdd(New Connoisseur() With{.Name="test1",.Pieces="1"}) 'This line will not be added because CS.Name already contains "test1"
CS.IFNotExistsAdd(New Connoisseur() With{.Name="test2",.Pieces="1"})
```

The output looks like this

Output:

```
{"test1","2"}
{"test2","1"}
```

Comment: You should probably just use a [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-7.0) instead. Note that you can specify how equality should be determined when you create an instance. If you don't, reference equality will generally be used for classes and value equality will be used for structures and `Strings`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're question is not entirely clear. *IFNotExistsAdd* is not a valid method name for a List, so you have to create an extension method.

Create a Module (using the same namespace as the calling class)

```
Module Extensions

<Extension>
Public Sub IFNotExistsAdd(Of T)(list As List(Of T), item As T)
    If Not list.Any(Function(x) x.Equals(item)) Then
        list.Add(item)
    End If
End Sub

End Module
```

Then you need to add an Equals override to the class (I've also added an initialiser for the properties)

```
Public Class Connoisseur

Public Name As String
Public Pieces As String

Public Sub New(name As String, pieces As String)
    Me.Name = name
    Me.Pieces = pieces
End Sub

Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
    If TypeOf obj Is Connoisseur Then
        Return EqualsItem(CType(obj, Connoisseur))
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Public Function EqualsItem(obj As Connoisseur) As Boolean
    Return obj.Name = Me.Name And obj.Pieces = Me.Pieces
End Function

End Class
```

You can then run add items to the list and it will only add those that are unique

```
CS.IFNotExistsAdd(New Connoisseur("test1", 1))
CS.IFNotExistsAdd(New Connoisseur("test1", 1))
CS.IFNotExistsAdd(New Connoisseur("test2", 2))
```

This will only add test1 and test2.